# WordPress free shipping if country and payment gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a small problem trying to set up free shipping in latest Woocommerce (2.6.x) if certain conditions are met.

Customer wants to set a free shipping if "cash on delivery" is chosen, price is over X€ and certain country is chosen.

I was trying a lot of snippets I found, but nothing seems to work. I don't wish to use too many plugins (already have quite a few).

I need something like:

```
if ($country == 'DE' && $cart_total >= 100 && $payment_gateway == 'cod' ) {
    $shipping == 0; 
}
```

Thank you for all the answers in advance,
Jure

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Table Rate Shipping for WordPress](https://codecanyon.net/item/table-rate-shipping-for-woocommerce/3796656?ref=TetrixThemes) and I found a solution to my question. There is missing check for payment method, but that should not be that hard to find. Just in case somebody else finds it useful.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'sl_custom_shipping_rates', 10, 2 );

function sl_custom_shipping_rates( $rates, $package ) {

    foreach( $rates as $key => $value ) {

        if( $value->method_id == 'table_rate_shipping' && WC()->cart->cart_contents_total >= 100 && WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() == "DE") {
            $rates[ $key ]->cost = 100;
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```